# refresh antd table on datasource change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, antd

I have a page that contains a searchbar component and an antd table component and I want my antd table to refresh whenever the datasource is changed or when I search in the searchbar. For now my table only updates when I refresh the page so I added a `window.location.reload()` to my onSearch function in order for it to work as intended but I want it to update without having to refresh the whole page. Is there a way to do that?

Here's my table.js

```
export default function Table() {
const [dataSource, setdataSource] = useState([]);
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);
  fetch(`${apiEndpoint}/api/managed-list`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
   setdataSource(data);
   console.log(data)
              })
  .catch((err) => {
   console.log(err);
     })
  .finally(() => {
   setLoading(false);
     });
  }, []);

return (
    <div>
        
      <Table
        bordered={true}
        loading={loading}
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={dataSource}
        pagination={true}
      />
    </div>
  )}
```

here's my searchbar.js

```
function SearchBar() {
  const [searchedText, setSearchedText] = useState("");
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const onSearch = () => {
    navigate(`/search?q=${searchedText}`)
    //find out a solution to update without refreshing
    // window.location.reload()
    console.log(searchedText)
    fetch(`${apiEndpoint}/api/managed-list`,{
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        content:searchedText
      }), headers:{"Content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8",'Accept': 'application/json'}
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(message=>console.log(message))
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Input.Search
        placeholder="Enter Company Name or keyword..."
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSearchedText(e.target.value);
        }}
        onSearch={onSearch}
        onPressEnter={onSearch}
        enterButton ></Input.Search>
    </div>
  );
}
export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: Where is search bar component in component tree? at same level with table ?

Comment: @HDM91 Just above my table

Comment: You can use redux to change state and other components notify when changes occur, or simply have event handler in search bar that parent component handle it and update state and pass it to table component to re render, why you navigate in search handler?